# Equivalent of gnu `sort -R` on OSX?

Tags: macos, sorting

The GNU `sort` text utility features a non-standard `-R` option to randomize input lines.

OSX `sort` does not have this extension.  Is there similar functionality available in another text filter?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you want, you can install GNU `sort` through GNU's [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/) package over [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), which is a package manager for OS X.

Running this would install Homebrew.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then just follow the installation instructions. When Homebrew is installed, run

```
brew install coreutils
```

This will install GNU sort as `gsort`, so you can use it like `sort` on any GNU Linux.

---

Alternatively, have a look at these Stack Overflow questions, which mention a couple of methods:

[How can I randomize the lines in a file using a standard tools on Redhat Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886237/how-can-i-randomize-the-lines-in-a-file-using-a-standard-tools-on-redhat-linux)
[How can I shuffle the lines of a text file in Unix command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153882/how-can-i-shuffle-the-lines-of-a-text-file-in-unix-command-line)

Or take a look at this commandlinefu.com page:

[Randomize lines (opposite of | sort)](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3611/randomize-lines-opposite-of-sort)

Comment: The homebrew option works, as would the linked awk or perl constructions (though I imagine they are slower.)  The rest are no go, as they are GNU-only.

Answer (score 8):

On OS X, if you don't want to install homebrew (but you really should), you could use `perl` or `ruby`:

```
perl -MList::Util -e 'print List::Util::shuffle <>'
```

or

```
ruby -e 'puts STDIN.readlines.shuffle'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `shuf` or `sort` from `coreutils` package, but then you've to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `PATH` in `~/.bashrc` file, for example:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Alternatively you can try `ex`:

```
ex -s +"%s/^/\=reltimestr(reltime())[-2:].' '" +"sort n" +"%s/^\S* //" +%p -cq! /dev/stdin
```

<sup>Source: [How to shuffle a list in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17644064/55075)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could install the `rl` command via homebrew (`brew install randomize-lines`).

It is quite fast and has options to limit the number of returned items, as well as specify the delimiter (space instead of line feed, for instance).

(See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/42056195/43615.)